# Upsert Cosmos item TTL using Azure Data Factory Copy Activity

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, ttl

I have a requirement to upsert data from REST API to Cosmos DB and also maintain the item level TTL for particular time interval.

I have used ADF Copy activity to copy the data but for TTL, used additional custom column at source side with hardcoded value 30.

[image]

Noticed that time interval (seconds) updating as string instead of integer. Hence failing with the below error.

Details
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorDocumentDBWriteError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Documents failed to import due to invalid documents which violate some of Cosmos DB constraints: 1) Document size shouldn't exceeds 2MB; 2) Document's 'id' property must be string if any, and must not include the following charaters: '/', '', '?', '#'; 3) Document's 'ttl' property must not be non-digital type if any.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDbManagement,'

**ttl Mapping between Custom column to cosmos DB**

[image]

When i use ttl1 instead of ttl, it is getting success and value stored as string.

[image]

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the issue with additional columns in Copy activity. Even of you set it to int, it will change to string at the source.

The possible workaround is to create a Cosmos DB trigger in Azure function and add 'TTL' there.